# How to serialize JNothing as null

Tags: scala, lift-json, json4s

With lift-json backed json4s, if I do the following:

```
val foobar = ("foo" -> JNothing) ~ ("bar" -> 42) 
println(write(foobar))
```

The output is:

`{, "bar":42}`

which is not valid JSON. I would like to obtain:

`{"foo":null, "bar":42}`

Is there any way to serialize `JNothing` into `null`?

Comment: why do you need that? No foo element means it is `null` already

Comment: @Tala: the deserializer at the other end is expecting it, as a mandatory value that can be null.

Comment: Ussually this is overcome by setting `null` by default to these fields

Comment: @Tala: if I had control over the receiving end, sure. However, I am required to send {"foo":null, "bar":42}

Comment: I'd say that producing invalid JSON is a bug which should be reported...

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov: I am not sure if I am using `write` correctly, though. If I do `compact(render(foobar))` the output is correct.

Comment: I came across the same issue the other day. It's definitely a bug in json4s, so I filed an issue https://github.com/json4s/json4s/issues/114

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found that, if I replace `JNothing` for `JNull`, I get the results that I expect.